# joomla not showing new changes after uploading to live

Tags: database, caching, joomla, overriding, joomla3.4

I'm working on a Joomla site. I have created some overrides for blog and single article, when I checked my site on local it displayed all things exactly as I want, but when I uploaded it to live some overrides for blog and single article were not showing as well as a plugin which I added on localhost. I cant understand the reason as I have checkede every thing on live, and it's working fine on local host.

NOTE: the site was already live. I added some new overrides for blog and single article. Before i uploaded new first I deleted all the existing code on live and cleared its DB, then i uploaded all new code and DB. Almost all the old things are working fine on live but not some new changes/overrides. I am using Joomla 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your browser cache first.

Best is to install akeeba backup in localhost and then take backup and Restore in live server.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your Joomla cache - it is most likely caching the old layouts, so you must clear it in order for it to display your overrides.

Comment: See what he has written "Before i uploaded new first i deleted all the existing code on live cleared its DB". Where from old layout caching will come?